# JOIN Tables in SQL Fiddle?

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

I am working on a SQL project from one of my courses, using SQL Fiddle. Somehow I cannot extract some information, I've tried all sorts of different queries but I cannot get the correct results.

I have the following three tables:

```
A(PK:Course_Code, Course_Name)

B(PK and FK:Course_Code, PK and FK: Book_ID, PK and FK:Title, PK and FK:ISBN)

C(PK:Book_ID, PK:Title, PK:ISBN)
```

I want to extract the `Book_ID` and Title for which `Course_Name = 'Data'` Management'.

Does anybody know the solution? I would really appreciate your help :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have u tried so far ?

Comment: Well - then share your fille - or copy the DDL for the tables into your post - you already did the DDL did'nt you? To test your queries`? So no need we need to retype that.

Comment: Please include example source data, example desired results, etc.  In fact, why not include your SQL Fiddle link to demonstrate what you want and what you've tried?

Comment: you could share the sqlfiddle link too. And this seems like a pretty straight forward join

Comment: Its something alog `SELECT C.Title, C.Book_ID FROM A join B (on correct PK between A and B) join C (on correct PK between B and C) where A.Course_Name == 'Data Management'`   - btw. B has way to many PK/FKs

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT C.BOOK_ID, C.TITLE
  FROM A, B, C 
 WHERE A.COURSE_CODE = B.COURSE_CODE 
   AND B.BOOK_ID = C.BOOK_ID 
   AND A.COURSE_NAME = 'Data Management'
```